# JMX to k6 conversion : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unrecognized element: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, k6, jmeter-to-k6

I'm using JMeter to k6 converter ([jmeter-to-k6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmeter-to-k6)) and trying to convert a jmx file to a k6 script. When I execute following command to convert it, I get the following error and the conversion stops.

**command**

```
jmeter-to-k6 C:\Tests\test.jmx -o k6
```

**Error**

```
(node:23544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unrecognized element: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup
    at element (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element.js:50:27)
    at module.exports.args (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element.js:1:102)
    at elements (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\elements.js:17:43)
    at module.exports.args (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\elements.js:1:102)
    at Object.hashTree (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element\hashTree.js:4:10)
    at element (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element.js:53:36)
    at module.exports.args (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element.js:1:102)
    at elements (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\elements.js:17:43)
    at module.exports.args (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\elements.js:1:102)
    at Object.TestPlan (C:\Users\SFernando\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmeter-to-k6\src\element\TestPlan.js:14:17)
(node:23544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimate Thread Group isn't in tool's [list of supported JMeter components](https://github.com/loadimpact/jmeter-to-k6/blob/master/doc/BEHAVIOR.md)

You can open an issue in github project for adding such support